# Which 'Pacific Rim' Jaeger had the most overall kills?

Tags: pacific-rim, kill-count

I'm trying to identify which Jaeger had the most Kaiju kills. On screen ‎Gipsy Danger had the most Kaiju kills with 9 but it seemed that some of the others had been battling (off screen) for years while Gipsy was 'in retirement'. I think ‎Striker Eureka is said to have 10 but haven't been able to identify other's tallies.

Comment: Gipsy Danger was the most effective. It closed the breach.

Comment: @Richard -Gipsy did close the breach but it took teamwork. They needed Striker to make a path.

Comment: @Morgan - There's a reason why they pay the quarterbacks ten times as much as the other positions...

Comment: @Richard -Here's the avg. pay of the top 5 NFL players in each of their respective position; Defensive End - $16.5 million, Quarterback - $15.2m, Offensive Tackle - $11.8m, Wide Receiver - $11.4m, Cornerback - $10.4m. The DEs are making more than the QBs. If the 300 pound defensive lineman spend their time playing whack-a-mole with the QB, he doesn't look so special :-) http://www.businessinsider.com/nfls-highest-paid-positions-sports-chart-of-the-day-2012-9

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you can see, the official "[Trading Cards](http://movies.cosmicbooknews.com/content/pacific-rim-battle-count-kaiju-kills-revealed-new-jaeger-trading-cards)" for the film Pacific Rim come complete with a Kaiju kill count;

Striker Eureka has the highest number of on- and off-screen kills with 11.

[image]

The [Pacific Rim wikia](http://pacificrim.wikia.com/wiki/Striker_Eureka) contains a complete listing of all kills made

Comment: There are trading cards!? I just bought the DVD and thought this was a great movie but had no idea it had such a following.

Comment: @Morgan - From what I can tell, they gave them away at cinemas along with the graphic novel.

Comment: How can Striker Eureka have 11 kills on the card when they say they have 7 kills in the movie. We don't see them smoke any Kaiju in the movie but we do see them get EMPd and finally nuked. There's a novel too!? What is canon? Damn, I'm way behind the curve.

Comment: I believe Chuck also brags about breaking the record when they're interviewed on the telly.

Comment: @morgan - The wiki says that the movie is canon but the novelisation isn't.

Comment: @Liath -You're right. I just re-watched the movie. Striker got #10 in Sidney near the beginning of the movie. They were involved in two more battles but that was their last kill.

Comment: Gipsey Danger had 5 kills before 'retirement'. After refit and bringing Raleigh out of retirement, they get 2 more in Hong Kong and 2 more (including a category 5 Kaiju) on the ocean floor. This brings their Jaeger-v-Kaiju head count to 9. That's still 1 less than the previously stated record of 10 for Striker Eureka... It just occurred to me while typing this that when Striker tapped off their payload to plow-the-road for Gipsy to reach the "Breach", they did kill one of the Kaiju---I missed that one, so they did get 11 kills. The card is right.

Comment: They should consider weighing the difficulty of kills to determine most effective Jaeger. Killing a category 5 Kaiju should count more than killing a cat 2.

Comment: @iMerchant - Yeah, but you'd also need some sort of handicapping system for the efficacy of the Mecha and the emotional instability of the pilots. Also, how do you score *"destroyed the entire Kaiju civilisation"*?

Comment: @Valorum - I would not include dropping a nuke-charged Jaeger through the wormhole to end the threat forever as part of my calculation of who was the best one-on-one fighting Jaeger. Clearly ending the threat once and for all by nuking the baddies in a Dues Ex Machina-esque move sort of trumps everything, but that doesn't really show the effectiveness of the Jaeger's effectiveness. I would argue the fighting of the 3 Kaiju (including a cat 5) before falling in the wormhole is a better measure of the effectiveness.

Answer (score 0):

Technically gypsy had the most kills cause of the final nuclear explosion in the kaiju's dimension

Comment: The question was referring to individual kills. As the comment below it indicates, Striker actually did most of the hard work, Gypsy was simply the warhead/payload